# Updating rwhois contact information to satisfy blacklisting agent

Tags: whois

I've had a VPS for several years, operating at the same IP address. Recently my IP address was listed at MIPspace for sending "unsolicited email marketing". I am NOT in the business of email marketing.

I've been attempting to resolve the issue with MIPSpace, but they refuse to discuss any problems, or potential solutions with me because the rwhois entry for this IP address is listed under my ISP, and not me, or my company. They suggested that my ISP run an rwhois server to reflect the "correct" ownership of this IP address.

Is there anything on a technical front I can do on my server to help this situation? Would running rwhoisd with a certain configuration help, or does my ISP need to on one of their servers? I'm running debian-jessie.

I've tried asking MIPSpace for advise on what I can do, but it's almost as if there's some sort of HIPAA-type law preventing them from disclosing anything unless the rwhois has my name on it.

Answer (score 1):

This has to be done by the ISP. Only the authoritative owner can configure the RWHOIS records for the IP addresses they own. Tell the ISP you need the RWHOIS records for your IP address in question and they should be able to do it. You should note not all ISP's do this and some will refuse to update the RWHOIS records and your only option would be to either have the ISP deal with the blacklist operator on the blacklist entry or to request the ISP provide you a new IP address.